# Why is may array returning empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hi I am new to react and am trying to use onSelect to return on array of items that are associated with that name. I am using the dot filter method to filter an array so that only items with the same key as the name that is selected appear. However my array returns empty.

```
class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {

  state = {
    selected: 'Brands',
    statelist: [
  {name: "Brands",
    items: ["1", "2", "3"]
  },
  {name: "Films",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  },
  {name: "Holiday Destination",
    items: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
]

  };



  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
    const myList = this.state.statelist;
    const myItemDetails = myList.filter(items=>items.key === key);
    console.log(myItemDetails)

  }


  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(this.state.statelist, selected);
    const {statelist} = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
        />

      <Items Items={Items[selected]}/>

      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

Comment: State updates are asynchronous, so the `console.log(myItemDetails)` will only display the state from *before* the update.

Answer (score 3):

According to your data-structure, you need to use use item.name to check for the selectedKey

```
myList.filter(items=>items.name === key);
```

**Note:** you must make sure that you are not updating stateList state after filtering the array, otherwise your your state will loose the data

Instead you must use another state variable to store filtered list or apply the filter while render instead of storing the filtered value in state